# Is it possible to boot from an SSD enclosure if I have Windows To Go

Tags: boot, ssd, enclosures

Can I boot up from an SSD enclosure using Windows 10 Enterprise (which has Windows To Go) on my laptop? I am planning on using [this enclosure](https://www.walmart.com/ip/StarTech-2-5-USB-3-0-External-SATA-III-SSD-Hard-Drive-Enclosure/29016166?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&adid=22222222227019623545&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=40881029312&wl4=pla-78811134152&wl5=9033255&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=online&wl12=29016166&wl13=&veh=sem&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI4427ys2W3wIV9h-tBh00IQLtEAQYBiABEgKts_D_BwE) for the Samsung 850 EVO SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can. Windows To Go is a feature in Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Education that enables the creation of a Windows To Go workspace that can be booted from a USB-connected external drive on PCs.

Using a USB drive that has not been certified is not supported.

We can check hardware considerations for Windows To Go: For USB drives and For host computers in [Windows To Go: feature overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview)

And how to use Windows to Go in Windows 10, we can refer to the article

How to Use Windows to Go in Windows 10

https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/10703-windows-to-go-in-windows-10.html